# Related Item is not completely removed

Tags: development, csom

I am working on an SharePoint add-in an I am having a problem with related items.

Example:

I have an risk for example and that risk has one related item. I use code to read this item and display it.

I go to my risk and remove the related item. Code works fine and retrieves that the related item = "null".

But

If I go to the related item end delete it without removing it from my risk first. My code gets some value for my related Item and trows an error that the related item was deleted.

but in the risk there are no related Item shown so I cant remove it from there and my code doesn't stop to trow an error. To fix it I had to delete my risk and make it again or restore the deleted related Item from the recycle bin and remove it from my risk.

I also tried to empty the recycle bin.

Code:

```
risklist = site.OpenWeb(proj.ProjectSiteUrl.Replace(spClientCtx.Url, "")).Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
items = riskIssuelist.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
spClientCtx.Load( items );
spClientCtx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var risk in items)
{
    if (risk["RelatedItems"] != null)
    {
        //stuff
    }
    else
    {
        //stuff         
    }
}
```

Not exactly my code but it works something like that.

Comment: Could you post your code please

Comment: I will try it is bit complex I have to remove the unnecessary part first